# How do libraries interact with other code?

Tags: libraries, encapsulation

I've been reading about encapsulation and keep seeing comments about how changing the privacy of a class or adding getters and setters where there were none before can 'break the code' of people who use your library. I don't really understand this. I'm very inexperienced in programming, and my understanding is that you download a library onto your computer and it's included in the files of the program you're writing, so if the original author changed something in THEIR COPY of the library, it wouldn't affect your copy. Is this wrong? For example, is a library more like a website that your computer connects to through the internet and the original author can update, so that changes they make to it can affect how your code works?

Answer (score 0):

Software is constantly changing, so we must have a way to keep track of the different versions - hence software versions. When you download a library to use in your own program, you (usually, like with a dependency management tool) end up downloading a very specific version of that library.

If a library author was to change the interface to use it, developers using that library would also have to change how they use it when they download the version with those changes. Otherwise, it would break any code that follows an outdated interface.

As long as a library author follows proper versioning procedures, for instance including breaking changes in a new major version, and the changes improve the clarity of the library's interfaces without sacrificing other properties, then the argument is moot. Developers can either continue using the old version or update their code to be compatible with the new version.
Except for maybe in low resource, embedded systems that can use all optimizations available, like accessing object/structure properties directly rather than through a function.

Comment: "If a library author was to change the interface to use it, developers using that library would also have to change how they use it when they download the version with those changes." But what if the developer didn't download a new version? What if they just kept using the first version they downloaded?

Comment: @Urthona26 If they don't download/install a new version, then they won't be affected by the changes in the library, including any new features that may be added to it. They will still have the same version of the library that they started with.

Comment: "If a library author was to change the interface to use it,"  @urthona26 normally the library creator will ensure the backward compatibility is supported. Meaning if there are new functions added it will not just remove old functions but mention them as deprecated but still allow them to be used for certain timelined versions to avoid the impact of library upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

**Libraries**:

> By definition a collection of non-volatile resources used by computer
> programs, often for software development. These may include
> configuration data, documentation, help data, message templates,
> pre-written code and subroutines, classes, values or type
> specifications.

**Explanation**

> Let me spend time on defining in coding aspects: Lets say you have a
> create a soccer game, what does that need, field, ball, players,
> flags.
>
> All this we encapsulate in Class to make as Object Game which
> comprises all above.
>
> Now you start building game and realise you are spending redudant time making repeated player names, shirt design , details filling, etc.
>
> To avoid this you make functions which are business specific like 1. generate tshirts and pass (color, design , cloth type) and it returnes you tshirt object in return.
>
> Similary you get player information by passing country and his ID and all this details are return as Player object which have his name, place, country, contacts ets.
>
> This is how the functions in class behaves.

**Your ask**

> *privacy of a class or adding getters and setters, ...an 'break the code' of people who use your library*

> These are ways how you access the object parameters or set values for them , in some languages the getter and setters are auto generated and not required to explicitly set unless you need custom settings during class object creation.
> The best advantage of the getting and setter is it ensures the default class creation can be assigned some values which you dont want to change in defaults and also not allow people to enforce new values to that specific parameter of class.
> This is how the control is made in place during defining your class and its functions. getter and setter are functions as well with class variables having factility to get/set values as you define the function logic inside.

**You ask**

> *my understanding is that you download a library onto your computer and
> it's included in the files of the program you're writing, so if the
> original author changed something in THEIR COPY of the library, it
> wouldn't affect your copy. Is this wrong?*

> Yes think it like a CD Copy , I sent you a copy so you can use those info from the copy i made, but once i have new features and things added in CompactDisc(CD) it wouldnt be there in your copy i burnt  during that time hence you code uses the old version and may use till there is need to update.
> You can only get impacted if you take my new CD copy which is called as upgrading your software with my new library version.
> Normally big guys software dont immediately change the library in their systems unless there is thorough analysis done with 1. need, 2. security 3. bugs in old fixed in new. factors to address for a new upgrade.

**Happy Coding**

> - Software world is free of your mind to code so dont think what is wrong or right just code.
> - Take a Maths Library building task in hand use anything python, java, c#, objective C, swift, javascript ...
> - Create library with modules with Circle, Square, Polygon, Sphere objects
> - Each object they will have thier respective Classes created with theier paramters (circle sample : radius, center(x,y), etc and functions like setRadius, getCircumference, etc)
>   Similar way all objects makes thier own classes
>   Abstrat word you used means some function you make private that only class can internally access but not exposed to outside when you create new Maths Object.

Hope this was helpful, happy coding.